# Public function returning a list c#

Tags: c#, list, return

I have a block of code that basically creates a list of objects, and this code will be a part of a bigger program later on, and I need a function that would return the list to the program. I tried something like this:

```
//RETURN LIST FUNCTION
public List<WynikPorownania> Zwrlista()
{
    return listatf;
}
```

But it doesn't do the job since it's only available inside this block of code and I can't use the public specifier. Here is my code :

```
using System;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace dokselect
{
    class indexstan
    {
        public string index;
        public double standysp;
    }

    class WynikPorownania
    {
        public string Indeks;
        public int Ilosc;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Indeks + " : " + Ilosc;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ///////CONNECTION

            string conn = "CONNECTION STRING IS HERE";
            FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(conn);
            FbDataReader myReader = null;

            string sql = "select KARTOTEKA.indeks,STANMAG.standysp FROM kartoteka INNER JOIN stanmag using(ID_KARTOTEKA) WHERE stanmag.ID_MAGAZYN=10002;";
            FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand(sql, myConnection);

            myConnection.Open();
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            ///////LIST lista1
            List<indexstan> listadb = new List<indexstan>();
            double standysp;
            string index;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                index = myReader[0].ToString();
                standysp = Convert.ToDouble(myReader[1]);
                if(standysp<0)
                    {
                        standysp = 0;
                    }
                listadb.Add(new indexstan { index=index, standysp=standysp });
                //Console.WriteLine(myReader[0].ToString());
            }
            myConnection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(listadb.Count);


                //RETURN STANDYSP FUNCTION
                double zwr(string myIndex)
                {
                    var result = listadb.FirstOrDefault(listadb => listadb.index == myIndex)?.standysp;
                    return result ?? -1;
                }
                //zwr("EMPIS_DESKA_FASOLKA");

                //READ FROM TXT AND RETURN HIGHER
                string path = "C:/Users/Praktykant/Documents/textdocs/dok1.txt";
            
                List<WynikPorownania> listatf = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line =>
                {   
                    var linia = line.Split("=");
                    string index = linia[0];
                    int value = int.Parse(linia[1]);
                    if(value<0)
                    {
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    if(zwr(index)==-1)
                    {
                        return new WynikPorownania { Indeks = index, Ilosc = (int)zwr(index) };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new WynikPorownania { Indeks = index, Ilosc = (int)Math.Max(value, zwr(index)) };
                    }
                }).ToList();
                //DISPLAY ALL LISTATF CLASSES
                foreach (WynikPorownania WynikPorownania in listatf)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(WynikPorownania);
                }
                //RETURN LIST FUNCTION
                public List<WynikPorownania> Zwrlista()
                {
                    return listatf;
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nie znaleziono pliku z podanej sciezki. Blad zwrocil: "+ex);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podaj indeksy i wartosci w formacie 'indeks=wartosc'. Blad zwrocil: "+ex);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nie podales prawidlowego indeksu. Blad zwrocil: "+ex);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Zly format. Blad zwrocil: "+ ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I read some of your suggestions and I think I understand what the problem is. I rearranged the code this way:

```
using System;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace dokselect
{
    class indexstan
    {
        public string index;
        public double standysp;
    }

    public class WynikPorownania
    {
        public string Indeks;
        public int Ilosc;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Indeks + " : " + Ilosc;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        public List<indexstan> listadatabase()
        {
            string conn = "CONNECTION STRING";
            FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(conn);
            FbDataReader myReader = null;

            string sql = "select KARTOTEKA.indeks,STANMAG.standysp FROM kartoteka INNER JOIN stanmag using(ID_KARTOTEKA) WHERE stanmag.ID_MAGAZYN=10002;";
            FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand(sql, myConnection);

            myConnection.Open();
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            ///////LIST lista1
            List<indexstan> listadb = new List<indexstan>();
            double standysp;
            string index;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                index = myReader[0].ToString();
                standysp = Convert.ToDouble(myReader[1]);
                if (standysp < 0)
                {
                    standysp = 0;
                }
                listadb.Add(new indexstan { index = index, standysp = standysp });
                //Console.WriteLine(myReader[0].ToString());
            }
            myConnection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(listadb.Count);
            return listadb;
        }
        public double zwr(string myIndex)
        {
            var result = listadb.FirstOrDefault(listadb => listadb.index == myIndex)?.standysp;
            return result ?? -1;
        }
        public List<WynikPorownania> lista()
        {
            string path = "C:/Users/Praktykant/Documents/textdocs/dok1.txt";
            List<WynikPorownania> listatf = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line =>
            {
                var linia = line.Split("=");
                string index = linia[0];
                int value = int.Parse(linia[1]);
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    value = 0;
                }
                if (zwr(index) == -1)
                {
                    return new WynikPorownania { Indeks = index, Ilosc = (int)zwr(index) };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new WynikPorownania { Indeks = index, Ilosc = (int)Math.Max(value, zwr(index)) };
                }
            }).ToList();
            return listatf;
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                
                
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nie znaleziono pliku z podanej sciezki. Blad zwrocil: "+ex);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podaj indeksy i wartosci w formacie 'indeks=wartosc'. Blad zwrocil: "+ex);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nie podales prawidlowego indeksu. Blad zwrocil: "+ex);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Zly format. Blad zwrocil: "+ ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think that it's correct, even visual studio highlights the mistake, saying that listadb doesn't exist in this context. I don't really know where to go from here. Ps. Sorry if the code isn't 100% in english but I'm just a trainee at a company and I'm naming variables and functions how they told me to, when doing projects in the future I will surely remember to use English :D

Comment: What is your reason for using local functions here?

Comment: I suggest you extract the code that creates the list into its own method, which *can* be public (once WynikPorownania is public). You can then call that method from `Main`.

Comment: Unrelated: Especially in international settings, it's beneficial to stick with english naming, so a vast majority of readers can understand what classes and properties etc are supposed to be. Also, it is _always_ a good idea to stick with [standard dotnet naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). (+https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions)

Comment: Don't be so harsh, he's just "C:/Users/Praktykant" (eng. - Trainee)

Comment: @Auditive No one is being harsh (intentionally). These are all legit suggestions for improvement. Isn't that what we are all here for? _And_: if we are serious about it, all we ever are is trainees. There isn't quite one day I do not learn anything new.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing up things:

`public` means that a method, declared as `public`, can be used by other objects.

Your function is embedded inside a method, and as a result, it is not a `public` method: it's just a function, being embedded inside a method as and such, it is only accessible from within that method.

Comment: Also the list definition `List<WynikPorownania> listatf` is local to the Main `try ... catch` block and so will be out of scope and not accessible publicly.

Answer (score 0):

I just threw everything into a function and It works. If enybody has this problem in the future, Here is how it looks:

```
using System;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace dokselect
{
    class indexstan
    {
        public string index;
        public double standysp;
    }

    public class WynikPorownania
    {
        public string Indeks;
        public int Ilosc;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Indeks + " : " + Ilosc;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        public static List<WynikPorownania> funkcjalista()
        {
            ///////CONNECTION
                string conn = "CONNECTION STRING";
                FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(conn);
                FbDataReader myReader = null;

                string sql = "select KARTOTEKA.indeks,STANMAG.standysp FROM kartoteka INNER JOIN stanmag using(ID_KARTOTEKA) WHERE stanmag.ID_MAGAZYN=10002;";
                FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand(sql, myConnection);

                myConnection.Open();
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                ///////LIST lista1
                List<indexstan> listadb = new List<indexstan>();
                double standysp;
                string index;
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    index = myReader[0].ToString();
                    standysp = Convert.ToDouble(myReader[1]);
                    if (standysp < 0)
                    {
                        standysp = 0;
                    }
                    listadb.Add(new indexstan { index = index, standysp = standysp });
                    //Console.WriteLine(myReader[0].ToString());
                }
                myConnection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(listadb.Count);


                //RETURN STANDYSP FUNCTION

                double zwr(string myIndex)
                {
                    var result = listadb.FirstOrDefault(listadb => listadb.index == myIndex)?.standysp;
                    return result ?? -1;
                }

                //zwr("EMPIS_DESKA_FASOLKA");

                //READ FROM TXT AND RETURN HIGHER
                string path = "C:/Users/Praktykant/Documents/textdocs/dok1.txt";
            


                List<WynikPorownania> listatf = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line =>
                {
                    var linia = line.Split("=");
                    string index = linia[0];
                    int value = -1;
                    try
                    {
                        value = int.Parse(linia[1]);
                    }
                    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                    {
                        index += " - ZLE ZAPISANA LINIA";
                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        index += " - PODANO ZLA WARTOSC";
                    }


                    if (zwr(index) == -1)
                    {
                        return new WynikPorownania { Indeks = index, Ilosc = (int)zwr(index) };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (value < 0)
                        {
                            value = 0;
                        }
                        return new WynikPorownania { Indeks = index, Ilosc = (int)Math.Max(value, zwr(index)) };
                    }
                }).ToList();
            
                //DISPLAY ALL LISTATF CLASSES

                foreach (WynikPorownania WynikPorownania in listatf)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(WynikPorownania);
                }
            return listatf;
            
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            funkcjalista();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).